# How do I install Skype on 11.10 when using kubuntu (kde4.7)?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, skype

I have added the partner repository, however when issuing aptitude install skype the proposed solution is to remove all of libs concerning kde4, plasma, dolphin and a hundred other packages. That seems very wrong, I dont want to remove my kde4 plasma desktop just to install a 32bit program.

Help?

Answer (score 3):

**Skype, apt-get, aptitude**

With the apt-get:

Updating the package database:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update
```

Cleaning the package archives:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get clean
```

Looking packages:

```
:~$ apt-cache show skype
```

=>

```
Package: skype
Priority: extra
Section: net
Installed-Size: 29200
Maintainer: Brian Thomason <****>
Architecture: i386
Version: 2.2.0.35-0oneiric2
Recommends: sni-qt
...
Filename: pool/partner/s/skype/skype_2.2.0.35-0oneiric2_i386.deb
...
```

-> It is in the partner repositories /1/,/2/.

Simulation with the apt-get:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install -s skype


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  sni-qt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  skype sni-qt
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Inst sni-qt (0.2.5-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:11.10/oneiric [i386])
Inst skype (2.2.0.35-0oneiric2 Partner archive:11.10/oneiric [i386])
Conf sni-qt (0.2.5-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:11.10/oneiric [i386])
Conf skype (2.2.0.35-0oneiric2 Partner archive:11.10/oneiric [i386])
```

-> Will install two packages, shouldn't remove KDE.

apt-get help:

```
:~$ apt-get  --help
```

man pages:

```
:~$ man apt-get
```

With the aptitude you could ask why,why-not

```
 why          - Show the manually installed packages that require a package, or
                why one or more packages would require the given package
 why-not      - Show the manually installed packages that lead to a conflict
                with the given package, or why one or more packages would
                lead to a conflict with the given package if installed.
```

aptitude help/man pages:

```
:~$ aptitude --help


:~$ man aptitude
```

Maybe the

```
:~$ aptitude why-not skype
```

could tell what package(s) is/are conflicting with the skype.

**Oneiric & muon**

The Muon is a GUI  /3/,/4/. Kubuntu 11.10 /5/ is using the muon suite (Muon Software Center,Muon Package Manager) as default package manager GUI.

Links

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Kubuntu
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu
3. http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/
4. http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/introducing-qapt-and-the-muon-package-manager/
5. https://wiki.kubuntu.org/OneiricOcelot/Final/Kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need to add any repository. The latest version of skype comes with the package manager **Muon**. Just open Muon and search for skype. you will notice its the 2.2.x version of it. Right click on the package and select install. Then apply it. Done.

Also you are correct, the removal of all of those packages is not needed to install Skype (It would be crazy). Maybe the repository you added had something wrong.

INFO - http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/09/26/muon-package-management-suite/ (Additional info about Muon)

Comment: I find it strange that Skype 2.2.x is not in the repos in KDE and updated to the latest libraries in the KDE platform since I can see it in Ubuntu and both share almost the same repos. I will install KDE tomorrow just to test this out. Of course doing the same as the OP did.

Answer (score 0):

The removal of those packages is exactly what happened to me when I installed Skype. It broke my Plasma desktop effects.

Then I had to re-install `plasma-desktop` and manually switch on again "**Enable Desktop Effects at Startup**" under **System Settings** > **Desktop Effects**. Also make sure to use `XRender` under **Desktop Effects** > **Advanced** > **Compositing Type**, in case `OpenGL` isn't working for your graphics card.